Performance issues saving and reading into .csv file (1.5 milion lines)
I need to use Powershell to receive a load of data up to 1 500 000 rows, save into as a file (with correct CLRF encoding), and them immidately after use this file with another command. I find it hard to make it run smoothly, it often freezes and can take up to an hour to procees. I'm not an advanced user of Powershell or any other terminal tool.
More specific, I'm using Salesforce CLI (used to be known as SFDX), and command to query and bulk delete data. Unfortunately, the output of query cannot be streamlined into the delete, as delete must receive a path to text file with all record IDs. Query command does not have dedicated option with Path parameter that would optimize export When I run this query command, I get a constant stream of strings in the terminal window (screen below).
Currently I'm using this approach - saving all Query results into variable, exporting this variable as CSV file, passing path to that file into delete command.
# Create a temporary file
$tempFile = New-Item -ItemType File -Force -Path ./scripts/dataInsertion/tempFiles/queryTemp.csv

# Execute the query and save the result to the temporary file
$queryResult = sf data query -q "SELECT Id FROM $sObjectName LIMIT 1500000" -b --wait 1 -o $sandboxName -r "csv"

$queryResult | Set-Content -Path $tempFile


# Execute the delete command using the temporary file as a parameter
sf data delete bulk -s $sObjectName -f $tempFile -o $sandboxName


Remove-Item $tempFile

Is there any space for improvement?


The sf data query line likely can't be improved further but the next line instead of Set-Content you can try with [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($tempFile.FullName, $queryResult)

Good point, @Santiago, but Set-Content -Path $tempFile -Value $queryResult is simpler, with similar performance.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Hard to tell if this will be a performance improvement but worth a try, you can use Start-Process with -RedirectStandardOutput to save the output generated directly a file.
$path = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'scripts/dataInsertion/tempFiles/queryTemp.csv'
Start-Process sf -NoNewWindow -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput $path -ArgumentList @(
    'data'
    "query -q `"SELECT Id FROM $sObjectName LIMIT 1500000`""
    '-b'
    '--wait 1'
    "-o $sandboxName" 
    '-r csv'
)

sf data delete bulk -s $sObjectName -f $path -o $sandboxName
Remove-Item $path


I do not know how your tool works, but you could use a pipeline.
$arrayStrings | ForEach-Object {write-host $_}

I mean, you can work with the stream of strings that you receive, so that you can then put a string in your query.
That is, the pipeline passes the string to your request in the form in which it was received ( $_ ), the string can be converted if it needs to be processed before the request. The pipeline will continue to run until the lines run out

Unfortunately, the output of query cannot be streamlined into the delete, as delete must receive a path to text file with all record IDs.

You can transform your query so that you get a string that has all the data to delete. To then reformat the response so that it can be inserted into the deletion request.
Something like
$a = "123 345 678"
$b =  $a -split " "
$b[0] 
123
$b[1]
345
$b[2]
678

